# How to set Spinner text in android coming from server

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am working on android application in which i am getting string values from server. I want to set display text of my spinner from string value coming from server. For example if it String value from server is "O+" then the display text of the spinner should be "O+". Given below is my code, please guide me for this.

```
        private String[] state = { "O-", "O+", "A-", "A+", "AB-", "AB+", "B-", "B+" };

        Spinner spinnerOsversions;

        spinnerOsversions = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_BloodGroup);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state);
        adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerOsversions.setAdapter(adapter_state);
        spinnerOsversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Get values from server with help of a webservice and store in an array of strings / objects and use adapter for same.

Comment: Thanks @KanakSony for your reply. Can you please give me some little bit code snippet according to my code, assume the coming value from server to be "O+"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your server text contains as one of its choices: "O+".

To find and compare the position of "O+" in the Spinner use this:

```
 String  CompareValue= "O+";

if (!CompareValue.equals(null)) {
        int SpinnerPostion = adapter_state.getPosition(CompareValue);
       spinnerOsversions.setSelection(SpinnerPostion);
        SpinnerPostion = 0;
    }
```

Comment: works like a charm.. Thank you so much. Can you pleas just explain me the meaning of (!CompareValue.equals(null))? Why you are comparing it with null value?

Comment: Just for avoid null pointer exception.. Incase your server value return error.

Answer (score 2):

```
    String[] stateArray = { "O-", "O+", "A-", "A+", "AB-", "AB+", "B-", "B+" };
    String statePosition = "";       
    for (int i = 0; i < stateArray.length; i++) {
         if (stateArray[i].equals(result.getStateSelected())) { // result.getStateSelected() is your service response
             statePosition = stateArray[i]; 
             return ;
         }
     }

   spinnerOsversions.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(statePosition), true);
```